# IsNullOrEmpty with Object

Tags: c#

IsNullOrEmpty is used with strings to check if a string is null or empty.
Is there an equivalent with an object to see if any object is null or not?
I assume we can do

```
    obj1 != null
```

but not sure if there is any other way...

Comment: You mean, like, a simpler way?..

Comment: What I think he's asking is, "if we don't know whether a non-null object is a string or not, what's the best way?" string.IsNullOrEmpty() barf's on a non-string object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

a null string is null, an empty string is ""

isNullOrEmpty requires an intimate understanding about the implementation of a string.  If you want one, you can write one yourself for your object, but you have to make your own definition for whether your object is "empty" or not.

ask yourself:  What does it mean for an object to be empty?

Comment: If it has no properties/values.... It can happen, it's the reason for my Google-quest right now.  This post gave me hope for a second. :-/

Comment: @RJB what do you mean by "it" when you said `"it can happen"`

Comment: To get specific, it's a 3rd party Excel reader library that parses each cell value into an object within a DataSet.  If the cell is blank, the object is empty: {}, and {} == null returns false.

Comment: @RJB `var isNullOrHasNoProperties = obj == null || !obj.GetType().GetProperties().Any()`;

Comment: Hmm, now it ignores bools because booleans have no properties, but reflection is probably a good call so I'll go down that road.... Thanks!

Comment: Yeah that worked, for a DataSet object it was (cell = cell.GetType().Name == "DBNull" ? null : cell)

Comment: I Totally agree what @SamIamsaysReinstateMonica have to say specially about "What does it mean for an object to be empty?"

What happends most of the time in practies is that developers wish to check if an object is null.

Answer (score 30):

I found that `DataGridViewTextBox` values and some JSON objects don't equal Null but instead are `"{}"`  values. Comparing them to Null doesn't work but using these do the trick:

```
if (cell.Value is System.DBNull)

if (cell.Value == System.DBNull.Value)
```

A good excerpt I found concerning the difference between Null and DBNull:

> Do not confuse the notion of null in an object-oriented programming language with a DBNull object. In an object-oriented programming language, null means the absence of a reference to an object. DBNull represents an uninitialized variant or nonexistent database column.

You can learn more about the [DBNull class here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 12):

```
obj1 != null
```

is the right way.

String defines `IsNullOrEmpty` as a nicer way to say

```
obj1 == null || obj == String.Empty
```

so it does more than just check for nullity.

There may be other classes that define a method to check for a sematically "blank or null" object, but that would depend on the semantics of the class, and is by no means universal.

It's also possible to create extension method to do this kind of thing if it helps the readability of your code.  For example, a similar approach to collections:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty (this ICollection collection)
{
    return collection == null || collection.Count == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code is perfectly fine **and the right way** (most exact, concise, and clear) to check if an object is `null`:

```
object obj = null;

//...

if (obj == null)
{
    // Do something
}
```

`String.IsNullOrEmpty` is a method existing for convenience so that you don't have to write the comparison code yourself:

```
private bool IsNullOrEmpty(string input)
{
    return input == null || input == string.Empty;
}
```

Additionally, there is a `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` method checking for `null` and whitespace characters, such as spaces, tabs etc.

Comment: Take a look at [`Optional`](https://github.com/mariusschulz/MiniMods/blob/master/MiniMods/Optional/Optional.cs) or the *Maybe monad* in general.

Answer (score 2):

You may be checking an object null by comparing it with a null value but when you try to check an empty object then you need to string typecast. Below the code, you get the idea.

```
if(obj == null || (string) obj == string.Empty)
{
   //Obj is null or empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need any other way? Comparing an `Object` reference with `null` is the least-verbose way to check if it's null.

Answer (score 0):

`IsNullOrEmpty` is essentially shorthand for the following:

```
return str == null || str == String.Empty;
```

So, no there is no function that just checks for nulls because it would be too simple. `obj != null` is the correct way. But you can create such a (superfluous) function yourself using the following extension:

```
public bool IsNull(this object obj)
{
    return obj == null;
}
```

Then you are able to run `anyObject.IsNull()`.

Comment: @hvd `obj` and `str` are just **names**. Justin could have used `aReallyLongNameForSomething` or `example`.

Answer (score -1):

object MyObject = null;

if (MyObject != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyObject.ToString()))
{
  ...
}

Answer (score -1):

To test if an object is null:

- instead of using `(obj1 == null)`
- you can use `bool bIsNull = object.Equals(obj1, null);`